# POSTGRESQL - SUM of all orders with the same customer for a given month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to produce a report with the total invoice amount for each customer in the month of December :

| date | customer | invoice amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12/2021 | AB1 | 40 |
| 02/11/2021 | AB2 | 60 |
| 12/12/2021 | CE6 | 1000 |
| 31/12/2021 | RF9 | 0.5 |

Could I get any pointers? I'm still fairly new to postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` for your purposes.

```
SELECT customer, SUM(invoice_amount) as total_invoice_amount 
FROM your_table 
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = 12 
GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow in my brain I was like "it must be a really complicated query" but I guess I was overthinking it!

Comment: My pleasure, sir! And if my answer to the original question was helpful, feel free to mark it as right.